# getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am working through some practice problems and I can't figure out why my code is returning so many copies.

**Here is the question:**

Write a function called "getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty".

Given an object and a key, "getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty" returns an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given key that are equal to ten.

Notes:
* If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
* If the array contains no elements equal to 10, it should return an empty array.
* If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an empty array.
* If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.

**This is currently what I have coded:**

```html
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, keys) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj[keys].length; i ++) {
      if (obj[keys][i] === 10) {
        arr.push(obj[keys][i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var obj1 = {
  numbers: [1000, 10, 50, 10],
  other: [10, 10, 10, 20, 40]
};

getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj1, 'other')
// this is what is returned: [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ]
```

There should only be 3 copies of 10 in the array but there are..6.

What is going on? any hints would be awesome.

Comment: Don't iterate over the object's properties since you already know the key... that makes it iterate twice because there are two keys and gives you 6 tens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over the keys in the object (there are two of them), and then looping over the items in obj.other, and adding anything that is 10 to the array (there are 3 of them).  So you add each of the 3 matches, twice.  So you get 6.

A much simpler solution would just be:

```
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, keys) {
    return obj[keys].filter(function(item) {
        return item === 10;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var newArr= [];
   for (var key in obj){
    for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++){
      if (obj[key][i] === 10){
      newArr.push(obj[key][i]);

      }
    }
   }
   return newArr;
 }
```